# Creating a Dynamic Hyperlink in excel

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, excel-formula

I have three columns of data (columns A, B, and C).

- Column A contains a number
- Column B contains a name
- Column C contains a URL

In cell E1, I have a drop down list that references the cells in column A.

I need a function that generates a hyperlink based on the number picked from the drop down menu using the cells that are adjacent in columns B and C.  In otherwords, if E1 = any cell in column A, then create a hyperlink with the adjacent cells in columns B and C...  more generally:

```
=IF(E1=[Any cell in column A],HYPERLINK([same row column C],[same row column B],"")
```

Is it possible to create a dynamic formula that will do this?  I have found similar questions, but none that ask precisely this, and I cannot seem to piece together my searches to come up with a solution.

thanks to any who help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDxrp.png)

I hope you looking for like this

formula:
=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(E1;A1:C5;3;0);VLOOKUP(E1;A1:C5;3;0))

Comment: I didn't do anything about dropdown list you can find from here:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b

Comment: that does it!  thanks.  I was actually just figuring out a much more complicated solution using =match and =offset, but this is much more simple.  thanks for taking the time to help a beginner.

Comment: No problem, I am happy to help

Comment: And I am new in stackoverflow could you check my answer if it really works :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe (if i'm mentally imagining your spreadsheet right) that you'd be better off using the VLookup function to retrieve the URL. If i'm wrong and it's reversed, the HLookup function may be what you need. They're similar, just depending on the pivot of whether you're aiming for a value in a row (Vlookup) or Column (Hlookup).

This article does a pretty good job of explaining HLookup:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

You can then use the lookup value for the HYPERLINK function to set the display text and the URL.

Comment: Thanks, for the help!  I will definitely dig into that article to learn about Hlookup.